# How to order by some multiple columns using LINQ

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, linq

this is my Order 
i want Inprogress and recently Modified Review on top reviewed by LoggedIn user mean my review should be on top

and then Inprogress and recently Modified Review on second reviewed by Other user

```
 (SomeQuery)
   .OrderByDescending(o => o.ReviewerId == loggeduser.UserId && 
                           o.Status == ReviewStatus.InProgress &&               
                           o.LastModified)
   .ThenByDescending(p => p.Status == ReviewStatus.InProgress && 
                          p.ReviewerId != loggeduser.UserId && 
                          o.LastModified)
```

> Error Igot is= Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and

Comment: *ReviewStatus.InProgress &&  o.LastModified)*, is LastModified of type bool? I suspect not, if that's the case you need to compare it to something... or else your logic is totally flawed...

Comment: LastModified is DateTime

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just compare with something

```
   .OrderByDescending(o => o.ReviewerId == loggeduser.UserId && 
                           o.Status == ReviewStatus.InProgress &&               
                           o.LastModified == true)
   .ThenByDescending(p => p.Status == ReviewStatus.InProgress && 
                          p.ReviewerId != loggeduser.UserId && 
                          o.LastModified == true)
```

Comment: LastModified is DateTime

Comment: i am getting error due to LastModified

Answer (score 0):

Use the following order

(SomeQuery).Where(where condition).OrderByDescending(order by condition).ThenBy(another order by condition if needed)